# slowcheetah not working for app.config

Tags: app-config, slowcheetah, web-config-transform, config-transformation

Im using slowcheetah to transform my web.config file for various environments and this all works as expected.  I want to do the same on app.config files but despite having slowcheetah available for these projects, when I right click on the app.config file, I have no options (add config transform)  from what I've read, slowcheetah is supposed to work on web.config and app.config.  Has anyone else used it on app.config files ?  Is there something I'm missing

** update

after several hours of headscratching I managed to figure out why this wasn't working, you have to install the vsix file from their website ! So I now have a transform option available for app.config, the only other issue is the fact that there is no preview option as there is for web.config files, no idea why that should be

Comment: anyone help ? can I assume it only actually works with web.config ? Ive uninstalled it, restarted vs then reinstalled and it makes no difference, it simply wont work with app.config

Answer (score 0):

In order to preview the transformation, you need to install VS marketplace tool:
[Configuration Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GolanAvraham.ConfigurationTransform)